# How to generate random order numbers for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to generate random order numbers like **R5U14D8PLA** for WooCommerce orders? All the plugins out there are sequential or crc32 hash numeric digits, but couldn't find a way that generates random order numbers (digits+letters)

Comment: Simply create a cutom field and generate your own order numbers. The existing order number is logical, as whenever you insert into a database each record should have a sequential number in sequence with when it was inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late but here's my take on this. Use the function rand(min, max) to generate a random output.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {

    $prefix = 'UK'; //you can create a random number for prefix
    $suffix = 'INV'; //you can create a random number for suffix
    $order_id = str_ireplace("#", "", $order_id);//remove # before from order id
    $digits = rand(10000, 99999);

    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $digits;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Comment: Hello. The problem with this is that if you use this on the file functions.php, every time you reload the list of orders it will show a new one.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce provides a filter `woocommerce_order_number`. This filter is applied in the `get_order_number()` in the file `includes/wc-abstract-order.php`.

This is where you can attach your function & create a prefix or suffix for your WooCommerce order number.

Please add the below code in your Current active themes **functions.php** file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {

    $prefix = 'R5U'; //you can create a random number for prefix
    $suffix = 'D8PLA'; //you can create a random number for suffix

    $order_id = str_ireplace("#", "", $order_id);//remove # before from order id

    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $suffix;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thank you dear, but what I mean is having the function generate a random order number like R5U14D8PLA, (without prefix-suffix). Example; order id 1000 has order number R5U14D8PLA, order id 1001 has order number is U7F9D3ZQN3